# mobile hamburger for mobile not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I have 2 issues with this code:

1. When the submenu on mobile is dropped down the "X" is not closing it back
2. I sorted the problem with the anchor links (#) that are in the sub level. They close the drop down menu but don't change the "X" back to the "hamburger"

Thank you in advance for your help. The temporary file is this one: http://www.un-poco.com/navtemp

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') 
        multiTg();
      else 
        cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) 
        cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      $('#cssmenu  ul ul li').on('click', function() {
        $("#cssmenu ul").hide();
      });
    }

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "",
      format: "multitoggle"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have tried all these options and still have problems with the second issue :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your css styling. you dropdown menu has a padding top. you can find the padding here **#cssmenu > ul**. The reason why the menu was not closing because the click was not fired on your x icon instead it was on your dropdown div. change the padding to margin which will move the entire div below that should work.

Comment: Thank you. It sorted the first issue, but still struggling with the second one

Answer (score 0):

Because in mobile view `ul` dropdown list is over to hamburger menu that's why your click event not trigger.
Try to use margin instead of padding in your `ul` styling. See below code -

CSS-

```
#cssmenu > ul {
    margin-top: 43px;
    float: right;
}
```

For getting back hamburger icon on dropdown item click you need to just change your `#menu-button` class like below code -

JS Code -

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      $('#cssmenu  ul ul li').on('click', function() {
        // add this line only in your code might be solve your issue
        $('#cssmenu').find('#menu-button').addClass('menu-opened').removeClass('menu-closed'); 
        $("#cssmenu ul").hide();
      });
    }

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "",
      format: "multitoggle"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you. It sorted the first issue, but still struggling with the second one